# Http Post send Big List not work in Production Server

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, iis, payload

When I send a large list using Post the server can not read the value. But this works on the homologation server and does not work on the production server.

Http post AngularJs

```
$http({
    url: $rootScope.raiz_ws + '/Import/Gravar',
    method: "POST",
    data: { 'model': model }
}).then(function (response) {
    alert(response.data.mensagem);
});
```

Controller C#

```
{
    try
    {
        var response = this.call.Save(model);
        this.oc.dados = response;
        this.oc.status = true;
        this.oc.mensagem = "Ok!";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        this.oc.status = false;
        this.oc.mensagem = e.Message;
    }
    return serializer.Serialize(this.oc);
}
```

Model

```
{
    public List<ImportMail> importMail { get; set; }
    public string YY { get; set; }
    public string XX { get; set; }
}
```

```
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string PP { get; set; }
    public string TT { get; set; }
}
```

The names of the variavels have been exchanged! This code works in the development and homologation environment with large lists but not in production! Can it be some IIS configuration?

Comment: It could be anything, add logging to your application, or check every log to help identify the issue. Doubt it'll be answered until you provide further information from the logs..

Comment: Have you checked your config in the file / IIS / whatever host you're using to make sure that you're not exceeding the max request size?

Comment: Are you transforming the data before sending the request? There is a common issue when the post request are transformed to query string as those has a size limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in the Web.config, I added this and it worked

```
<security>
   <requestFiltering> 
     <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2200000000" /> 
   </requestFiltering> 
</security>
```